# I want to make my navbar transparent and solid on scroll only with html, css and js. Can you please explain how?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I want to make my navbar transparent and solid on scroll only with html, css and js. Can you please explain how?

Down here you have my html part

```
<header class="header">

   <a href="#" class="logo">noname<span> noname</span></a>

   <nav class="navbar">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a>
      
      <i class='fa fa-circle' style='color: white'></i><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a>
      
      <i class='fa fa-phone fa-flip-horizontal'></i><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>

     
     
   </nav>

   <div class="icons">
      <div id="menu-btn" class="fas fa-bars"></div>
   
   </div>

   
</header>
```

Comment: You need to add your styles to your question. Please use a snippet instead and show us your styles and scripts.

Comment: Please add your style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, by scrolling down, the navbar gets smaller and opacity is changed to 0.5, when scrolling back up, its changed back to the initial style.

Initial idea is from: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_shrink_scroll

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        padding: 90px 10px;
        transition: 0.4s;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    
    #navbar a {
        float: left;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    #navbar #logo {
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    #navbar a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }
    
    #navbar a.active {
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        color: white;
    }
    
    #navbar-right {
        float: right;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
        #navbar {
            padding: 20px 10px !important;
        }
        #navbar a {
            float: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }
        #navbar-right {
            float: none;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>

<div id="navbar">
    <a href="#default" id="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
    <div id="navbar-right">
        <a class="active" href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
        <a href="#products">Products</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:210px;padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px">
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

<script>
    // When the user scrolls down 80px from the top of the document, resize the navbar's padding and the logo's font size
    window.onscroll = function() {
        scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.opacity = "0.5";
            document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "80px 10px";
            document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.opacity = "1";
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

[image]